# Generic Cast CSV to List

Tags: c#, csv, casting

I've written this method to cast a comma separated string into a List of its type:

```
public List<T> GetListFromString<T>(string commaSplited)
{
  return commaSplited.Split(',').Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

But it throws an exception saying 'The specified cast is not valid.' 
I've tested it with long input.

Comment: And what is your goal? Do you want to be able process lets say comma separated list of integers? Which are the inputs you are going to handle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code certainly works if *T* is *string* (I tested it).

If *T* is *something else*, say *int*, you will get this Exception.

**This Works**

```
List<string> result = GetListFromString<string>("abc, 123, hij");
```

**This Fails**

```
List<int> resultInt = GetListFromString<int>("23, 123, 2");
```

That is because one cannot cast or convert *string* to *int*, e.g. the following would fail too:

```
int three = (int)"3";
```

**The Fix**

```
public List<T> GetListFromString<T>(string commaSplited)
    {
        return (from e in commaSplited.Split(',') 
                select (T)Convert.ChangeType(e, typeof(T))).ToList();
    }
```

*However* all of the given strings must be convertable to *T*, e.g. the following would still fail:

```
List<int> resultIntFail = GetListFromString<int>("23, abc, 2");
```

because "abc" cannot be converted to type *int*.

Also, *T* must be some type that [System.Convert()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) knows how to convert to from a *string*.